# Word to describe something similar to a crook?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine someone that parades around under fake identities on an internet game, breaking the rules of the game but never getting caught. Using his self-made tools only for himself and perhaps to help others for merely information exchange. He never shares his tools with others, but uses them on others to help, rarely. He's humble and doesn't rise to the top from his tools and forever seeks others who does what he does.

How would you describe this person?

Comment: When you say "an internet game" do you mean the kind where wagers are staked or the kind where fun is had? Because that could change the possible answers; I'd say "A cheat" in the former case and "a hobbyist hacker" in the latter.

Comment: He's *humble*? Are you sure, because he doesn't sound humble to me. Are you trying to portray what he does in a positive or negative light? Do you think he shows *ingenuity* or *trollish behavior*?

Comment: He shows ingenuity due to the tools he makes, which makes his life easier on the game and automates things, but doesn't affect anyone else. The game is a game for fun...Like Neopets.

Comment: What is Neopets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about someone who breaks the rules, but does so in a way that people admire or respect, then a **noble outlaw** or **social bandit** might work.